# MVC5 model inheritance for form

Tags: c#, inheritance, model, asp.net-mvc-5

i currently encounter a problem with MVC5 in my development and i'm searching for a solution to this problem.
To Explain my problem i will simplify it :

currently i have two class inherited

```
public class Person
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Professor : Person
{
    public string Education { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

i have a form page to enter information :

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginForm("Creation", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form0" }))
{
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" name="actionName">SAVE</button>


    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="infogene">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/GeneralInformation.cshtml", Model)
        </div>

        @if ((bool)Session["ProductCodeIsReadOnly"])
        {
            <div id="infospec" class="">
                @if (Model.PersonID.StartsWith("P"))
                {
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/SpecialInformationProfessor.cshtml", AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Professor>(Model))
                }
                else if (Model.PersonID.StartsWith("S"))
                {
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/SpecialInformationStudent.cshtml", AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Student>(Model))
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

SpecialInformationProfessor/SpecialInformationStudent is a view that need a Professor/Student Model but the basic view is a Person.

this is my action

```
public ResultCode Creation<T>(T Person, string actionName) where T: Person
{
 //Here i need to get Person as an Professor(if the partial was the Professor One) or as an Student(if the partial was the Student One) but i get only the person information
 return ResultCode.OK;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

PS:this code is a concept one(was made for this question).

Comment: I don't think the framework supports this out of the box. Easier to write two separate methods that accept Student and Professor.

Comment: The problem is that model will still be a Person even if i put 2 functions it seems that the model sent by the form is the main view model.  I don't want to copy/past the complete view as soon as i add a new child object (this is a conceptual code but in the real case i have a lot more inherited object than 2.

Comment: The MVC way is generally to create different views(with different actions) and models but if you really want to generalize it like this look at implementing your own ControllerActionInvoker. Basically you have to decide what kind of Person to instantiate based on the post data and call the action method.

Comment: Yes i understand that but even in that case my view will have a Person model. All my views have the same base form info but some info differe with the inheritance. So the probleme here is not the controller itself with actions cause they receive the model. The problem is that my view submit a different model that the one i need. The only way i see for the moment is to copy past the same page for each inherited object and just change the first line @model Person by the correct object... but that's ugly and it will be a lot of copy past

Comment: You don't really submit a model. You submit data within your form tag. Then on the server side there is the model binder that decides how to bind the data and the action invoker that decides what action has to be called. The point is: the framework uses your action method parameters to instantiate a Person based on the posted data. If you want to instantiate something else you have to implement it yourself.